# Linux software automated install

Tags: ubuntu, automation

I need a really simple way to automate software installation after a fresh install of ubuntu. I currently use a shell script to install the software and packages which clocks in at 800+mb which includes updating ubuntu.

However, after copying the files, due to permission issues and the need to open a terminal to execute the script, it is quite user unfriendly. I need a solution kinda like a installation wizard or somesort that will allow me to execute in a single click.

I tried making a deb package, however it doesn't allow me to update ubuntu while running a deb package.

PS. No network or internet installs, thanks.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [Puppet](http://www.puppetlabs.com/) or [Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/Documentation-v2.x), which are two of the most well-known for this specific task.  I know alot of developers that love Capistrano, but I'd look into both.  Puppet is pretty easy to set-up.  Shell scripts work, however, using an automatic system like these two option will allow you to set up multiple environments and automatically deploy certain applications to certain environments giving you complete control of post-install installs.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu has a couple of option including kickstart used in Redhat. Another very interesting option is [Preseeding](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/installation-guide/i386/appendix-preseed.html)

A Google search leads to this link
[Automatic Installation](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/installation-guide/i386/automatic-install.html). It offers a number of alternative.

Answer (score 0):

See this thread:

http://ask.debian.net/questions/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-non-interactive-installers-that-include-a-custom-set-of-packages